# Export Excel 2003 file from MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, excel, razor

I found a nice solution to my problem which is export Excel 2003 file from MVC3. I used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/263106/Export-Tabular-Data-in-CSV-and-Excel-Formats-Throu?fid=1656064&PageFlow=Fluid) code and it works perfectly but only with Excel 2007 and Excel 2010. What I need is some solution that will make this code to work with Excel 2003 as well. I guess there is a way to do that, but I am still looking for the solution. In my project I already use this code in many places and I don't really feel like changing it at whole. I will be very thankful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

Excel first began to use the xml-type spreadsheet in 2007. To get it into an Excel 2003 format, you would have to recreate the xls 2003 binary file format, which would be very difficult without using the Excel library.

There is a utility that allows 2003 users to open an xlsx file:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/open-an-office-excel-2007-workbook-in-an-earlier-version-of-excel-HA010014107.aspx

That might help you on the client side.

Comment: How can I fix it by using the Excel library?
Solving this problem on the client side is quite impossible as my clients don't want to be disturbed by additional downloads and updates.